# Google calender API integration error Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request()

Tags: php, google-api, guzzle, google-calendar-api

I follow all the steps of google calendar api Quickstart, But i am getting error.

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to
>   GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given,
>   called in
>   /home/yippywow/public_html/ikondata/pvr/wp-content/plugins/booking_google/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php
>   on line 87 and defined in
>   /home/yippywow/public_html/ikondata/pvr/wp-content/plugins/booking_google/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php
>   on line 126

Please help Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error message is telling you everything and the same we can say to you, you are passing wrong parameter to Guzzle `request` method, `Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given`, so check what and where are you passing.

Comment: I don't have experience with guzzle. i dont what and where i am passing in guzzle

Comment: It's okay, but somewhere you are doing HTTP request with Guzzle help, right? Something like `...->request('GET', $url, $parameters);`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Yes @MyMomSaysIamSpecial 

`return substr($method, -5) === 'Async'
            ? $this->requestAsync(substr($method, 0, -5), $uri, $opts)
            : $this->request($method, $uri, $opts);
    }`

Comment: Before this return line, write `var_dump($opts);` and check what it contains, must be array, but in your situation its probably `false`, or just empty, fastest solution is write something like `$opts = !empty($opts) ? $opts : []`, this will set `$opts` as empty array if `$opts` doesn't exist, and will leave untouched if does. But in this case check your application logic, because behaviour can change.

Comment: okay sir thanks!! let me check.